# Plotting Time and float value using python matplotlib from File

Tags: python, file, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I am having a text file with time and a float value. I have heard that it is possible to plot these two columns using matplotlib. Searched similar threads but could not make it happening. My code and Data are-

```
import math
import datetime
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
with open('MaxMin.txt','r') as f_input:
csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=' ',     skipinitialspace=True)
        x = []
        y = []
        for cols in csv_input:
            x = matplotlib.dates.date2num(cols[0])
            y = [float(cols[1])]
# naming the x axis 
plt.xlabel('Real-Time') 
# naming the y axis 
plt.ylabel('Acceleration (m/s2)') 
# giving a title to my graph 
plt.title('Accelerometer reading graph!')
# plotting the points 
plt.plot(x, y)
# beautify the x-labels
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
# function to show the plot 
plt.show()
```

And part of the Data in MaxMin.txt

```
23:28:30.137 10.7695982757
23:28:30.161 10.4071263594
23:28:30.187 9.23969855461
23:28:30.212 9.21066485657
23:28:30.238 9.25117645762
23:28:30.262 9.59227680741
23:28:30.287 9.9773536301
23:28:30.312 10.0128275058
23:28:30.337 9.73353441664
23:28:30.361 9.75064993988
23:28:30.387 9.717339267
23:28:30.412 9.72736788911
23:28:30.440 9.62451269364
```

I am a beginner in Python and on python 2.7.15 in windows 10 pro(64 bit). I have installed numpy,scipy scikit-learn already. Please help.

[Final Output Graph from complete Data Set. Thanks @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgZez.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you made in the original attempt is actually pretty minor. Instead of appending the values from the loop you redefined them. 
Also you would need to use `datestr2num` instead of `date2num`, because the string read in is not yet a date.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
with open('MaxMin.txt','r') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    x = []
    y = []
    for cols in csv_input:
        x.append(matplotlib.dates.datestr2num(cols[0]))
        y.append(float(cols[1]))
# naming the x axis 
plt.xlabel('Real-Time') 
# naming the y axis 
plt.ylabel('Acceleration (m/s2)') 
# giving a title to my graph 
plt.title('Accelerometer reading graph!')
# plotting the points 
plt.plot_date(x, y)
# beautify the x-labels
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
# function to show the plot 
plt.show()
```

[image]

My recommendation for how to make this easier would be, to use numpy and convert the input to datetime.

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x,y= np.loadtxt('MaxMin.txt', dtype=str, unpack=True)
x = np.array([datetime.strptime(i, "%H:%M:%S.%f") for i in x])
y = y.astype(float)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

---

Concerning the ticking of the axes: In order to have ticks every half a second you can use a  `MicrosecondLocator` with an interval of 500000.

```
import matplotlib.dates

# ...

loc = matplotlib.dates.MicrosecondLocator(500000)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))
```

Comment: Nice code. Running perfectly but only three X axis values are being displayed when the number of records are more than 100. Unfortunately I have an average 2000-5000 records per file. How to control the gap (If I zoom the curve, it is automatically adjusting, but in normal view, atleast a per second value on X axis is required. Any help in that? @ImportanceOfBeingErnes

Comment: It's hard to get some automatic labelling with more than the automatic number of ticks. If using a custom ticker, it's possible to get more ticks for the seconds-range, but then it will fail for zoomed in plots. Do you need to zoom in at all? (If not, what's the range of values to show on your x-axis, i.e. the first and last datum?)

Comment: You can view the sample data in my OP. I have no idea what the proper range should be, but a 0.5 sec gap will do. No there is absolutely no need to zoom the graph. I was trying to see how the x axis labels are automatically changing with that. I have also provided a drive link for the complete file in a comment here. You can take the entire data from it and see. Trying with something like-----          #Custom Format                                                   
        myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S.%f')
        plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

Comment: Without the need to zoom, it's rather easy. I updated the answer.

Comment: Almost 90% of what I want. Changed 5 to 10 in Milisecond to get in seconds. However is it possible to display in HH:MM:SS format and suppress the five zeros after second. I have uploaded the graph.

Comment: Yes, use a `DateFormatter` and specify your format.

Comment: Thanks , plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')) did the trick

Answer (score 3):

You could use pandas to achieve this, first store your file in a .csv format:

```
import math
import datetime
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd #### import this library

df = pd.read_csv("path_to_file.csv", delimiter=' ', encoding='latin-1') 

x = df.ix[:,0]
y = df.ix[:,1]
# naming the x axis 
plt.xlabel('Real-Time') 
# naming the y axis 
plt.ylabel('Acceleration (m/s2)') 
# giving a title to my graph 
plt.title('Accelerometer reading graph!')
# plotting the points 
plt.plot(x, y)
# beautify the x-labels
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
# function to show the plot 
plt.show()
```

if the first colunm does not have a datatime format you may convert it to this format like `df.ix[:,0] = pd.to_datetime(df.ix[:,0])`
and you take the hour for example:

```
df.ix[:,0] = df.ix[:,0].map(lambda x: x.hour)
```

The output after running the code was like:

[image]

Comment: Sir, I am a beginner. So a little more explanation will be of extreme help. I have given a few sample data from the text file as I do not know exactly what format are they now (string/number/Date). I want to plot those data with clean data labels ( a total 900 data are there in the text file).

Comment: This answer assumes that OP is using `pandas`, which they are not.

Comment: I have panda installed and wouldn't mind using it if it solves the problem. The graph is now plotting, thanks @Rodwan. But the X axis values are unreadable.

Comment: what do you want exactly to show on the X axis? Is it like in the output I showed?

Comment: Yes But with 1500-2000 data :( see the screen I posted.

Comment: In this case you maybe need to show a histogram instead, could you please provide a like to the file you have and I will try to work it

Comment: In this case you could avoid `import csv`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is not assuming anything. Given that the user is a self-declared beginner I think it is correct to lead him toward the de-facto standard.

Comment: The file is available at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xs3Q1uMBPlkmMfKKy4VRNAhrdtN7pygg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: As you are data scientist, is it possible to cluster these data to have a cleaner graph using something like SVM or regression ? A beginner in machine learning too :)  @Rodwan

Comment: @user32185 My comment from above refers to [a version of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53814241/3), which did not speak about pandas at all, but just used it as if it was clear.

Comment: @Pratik I see that the X axis is about time which has differences in miliseconds, you could plot a graph for each second or a line for each second on the same plot? Like that you get a overview for the whole data you have.

Comment: That would be extremely helpful. But require some kind of filtering/averaging/ clustering, I think. However do not have any knowledge in this domain. So any help will be extremely useful.

Comment: I will do some experiments and show you some plots and then you see what helps you the most @Patrik

Comment: Thanks, waiting for your suggestion and guidance.